# get parameter' s data types of a procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, select, plsql

I have a list with all my procedures from my database in C#. I  need to get the data type of each parameter. For example,I have a procedure called insertmd with parameters: name,age. How to make a select from all_tab_columns that will only display ,for example for parameter name, just: varchar2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`all_tab_columns` is for tables. if you want to see the arguments to a procedure then do:

```
select * 
  from all_arguments 
 where data_type = 'VARCHAR2' 
   and object_name ='INSERTMD'
   and owner = 'YOURSCHEMA';
```

that assumes INSERTMD is a standalone procedure/function. if its in a package, then also filter on `package_name`

Answer (score 3):

i think it may clarify your view!

```
select ua.argument_name,ua.data_type,ua.object_name 
  from user_arguments ua;
```

just use this one for finding all augments.if any clarification please let me know

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to do it. This is what I was looking for:                                                                                   select data_type from all_arguments where argument_name='PASS'

Answer (score 2):

All the information you need should be in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS view.

Comment: Very sorry, I misread the tags. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are in MS SQL server, not Oracle. Hopefully Dazza has given you the correct answer.